# Interesting trouble with windows services and the Stop-Process cmdlet

Tags: powershell, process, windows-services, powershell-cmdlet

We have a few home-brewed windows services over here.  One of them is problematic, in that it won't always stop when asked.  It gets stuck in the 'Stopping' state sometimes.

Using powershell we're retrieving its PID and using the Stop-Process cmdlet to kill the related process, but that's not working either.

Instead we get a message about a service named `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Name` which obviously isn't our service, but the PID it references is.

Here's what we're doing to get our service to stop.  First, we use the Get-Service cmdlet:

```
$ServiceNamePID = Get-Service -ComputerName $Computer | where { ($_.Status -eq 'StopPending' -or $_.Status -eq 'Stopping') -and $_.Name -eq $ServiceName}
```

Then, with that ServiceNamePID, we get the PID and use that in the Stop-Process cmdlet

```
$ServicePID = (get-wmiobject win32_Service -ComputerName $Computer | Where { $_.Name -eq $ServiceNamePID.Name }).ProcessID
Stop-Process $ServicePID -force
```

That's when the Stop-Process cmdlet squawks about `Cannot find a process with the process identifier XYZ`, when in fact PID XYZ *is* the correct Process ID for the service, per the task manager.  Has anyone seen a problem like this before?

Comment: You using -ComputerName on Get-Service and Get-WmiObject. Is the service running on another machine?

Comment: Great point Keith, I just noticed that myself.  It seems too that Stop-Process can't be run on a remote box either?  Any thoughts on what I can do if the PShell script is running on a different machine (with admin rights to the other box?)

Comment: To add to my last note, I'm going to try wrapping the Stop-Process cmdlet inside Invoke-Command -ComputerName

Comment: Yup, that would be my next step. Make sure you've enabled remoting on the remote PC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to stop a process on a remote machine, use remoting e.g.

```
 Invoke-Command -cn $compName {param($pid) Stop-Process -Id $pid -force } -Arg $ServicePID
```

This requires remoting to be enabled on the remote PC and the local account has admin price on the remote PC.

Of course, once you're using remoting you could do the script using remoting e.g.:

```
Invoke-Command -cn $compName {
    $ServiceName = '...'
    $ServiceNamePID = Get-Service | Where {($_.Status -eq 'StopPending' -or $_.Status -eq 'Stopping') -and $_.Name -eq $ServiceName}
    $ServicePID = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | Where {$_.Name -eq $ServiceNamePID.Name}).ProcessID
    Stop-Process $ServicePID -Force
}
```

Comment: Thanks Keith.  Just in case not all of the remote machines in question have powershell installed on them, what if I were to call get-wmiobject win32_process -cn <remote computer> and then call Terminate() on the returned object?  Any warning bells you can think of?

Comment: That should work assuming the GWMI can connect to the remote machine.

Comment: This will hopefully work out great with some of our TopShelf services that can behave stupidly at times.